# Unsure how to use headers, "...was not declared in this scope" errors

Tags: c++, module, header

I'm working on an assignment where we take a working project (that is contained in one cpp file) and to split it up between several modules/cpp files. This is my first time working with header files, and I'm a bit unsure on what to do. I know that the header files are used for declaring structs and variables and such, but not much else. An error I'm frequently getting is "...was not declared in this scope. An example from my code;

In "cookie.h", I have the following code;

```
#ifndef _cookie_H_INCLUDED_
#define _cookie_H_INCLUDED_

struct Cookie {


int initialNumberOfRows;

/// Number of rows currently remaining in the cookie
int numberOfRows;

/// Number of columns currently remaining in the cookie
int numberOfColumns;


/**
 * The "shape" of the cookie.
 *
 * If crumbs[i] == j, then the cookie currently
 * has crumbs filling the j columns at row i
 */
int* crumbs;
};
```

However, when I try to run the program, I get the error "cookie was not declared in this scope", specifically originating from another header file, 'computerPlayer.h' The code from that section follows as;

```
#ifndef _computerPlayer_H_INCLUDED_
#define _computerPlayer_H_INCLUDED_
bool isADangerousMove (Cookie& cookie, int column, int row);
#endif // _game_player_INCLUDED_
```

I'm unsure on how to 'link' the header files together, if that's the right way to think about it?

Comment: From what you posted `cookie.h` is missing the `#endif`.

Comment: Did you include `cookie.h` in `computerPlayer.h` ?

Comment: Note: I'm *sure* the closing `#endif` fencepost in your `computerPlayer.h` header file... `#endif // _game_player_INCLUDED_` is just a type, right? You surely didn't accidentally use the same fencepost id in two different headers, right?

Comment: Does it *really* say "cookie was not declared in this scope", or does it say "Cookie was not declared in this scope"? When you call one thing `Cookie`, and another thing `cookie`, this kind of distinction becomes really important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `computerPlayer.h` from the compiler's point of view:

```
#ifndef _computerPlayer_H_INCLUDED_
#define _computerPlayer_H_INCLUDED_
bool isADangerousMove (Cookie& cookie, int column, int row);
#endif // _game_player_INCLUDED_
```

The compiler is trying to compile something that #includes this, so we can imagine that it's been inserted near the top of a source file. The declaration of `isADangerousMove` refers to `Cookie`, but the compiler has never heard of `Cookie`, so it refuses to compile this thing.

You could `#include "cookie.h"` at the top of `computerPlayer.h`, but that would be overkill. Instead, just use *forward declaration*:

```
#ifndef _computerPlayer_H_INCLUDED_
#define _computerPlayer_H_INCLUDED_
struct Cookie;
bool isADangerousMove (Cookie& cookie, int column, int row);
#endif // _game_player_INCLUDED_
```

This tells the compiler that there's a struct called `Cookie`. And what is a `Cookie`? For now, it doesn't matter. This is enough information for the compiler to compile the code -- which may include a call to `isADangerousMove` -- and produce an object file (say, `computerPlayer.o`). Later on, when the linker tries to link these object files together, it will look for the definition of this struct (which is in `cookie.h`) and if it doesn't find it, you'll get a linker error.

Comment: I tried doing the "struct Cookie;" fix, and it works great! However, I had other similar problems that were easily fixed with the inclusion of other .h files, and I'm going to try to fix the rest of this program on my own. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: There's one other thing that I can't figure out. In game.h, it says that "Cookie does not name a type". When I add in "struct Cookie;", or even "#include "cookie.h". It still gives me errors, "field cookie has incomplete type" and the original error, respectively. I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: @Josh: `struct Cookie;` is enough for this function declaration; it is **not** enough for a function (or struct or class) *definition*. In that case the compiler wants to know what a `Cookie` *is*. If `#include "cookie.h"` doesn't work, then I suspect there's something wrong with the header guards (though I'd have to see the code to be sure).